# How to read certain lines after a find some text?

Tags: bash, shell

How i can read a certain number of lines after find some text?

**Eg.:**

Read next 2 lines after find "Unix" on:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 4
UNIX
Test 5
Test 6
Test 7
Test 8
Test 9
```

Result can be:

```
Test 5
Test 6
```

Note: The "Unix" on last example is an argument, and so, it can be any other text.

What i have:

I'm still out of ideas, need just a light. Thinking on create another script to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '$0 == "UNIX" {i=1;next};i && i++ <= 2' file
Test 5
Test 6
```

**Explanation**

- `/^UNIX$/{i=1;next}`: if we see `UNIX`, we set variable `i = 1`, processing to next input.
- If variable `i` is set (meaning we saw `UNIX`), `i && i++ <= 2` only evaluated to true value in next two lines after `UNIX`, causing `awk` performed default action `print $0`.
- Before seeing `UNIX`, `i` was not defined and begin at 3rd line after `UNIX`, `i` had a value greater than 2, which make expression `i && i++ <= 2` evaluated to false, causing `awk` do nothing.

Comment: After test you solution im getting this error message: 

error systax near line 1
bailing out near line 1

Comment: @Cold: What did you run? Please note that the `$` sign at beginning of my answer is shell prompt, not part of `awk` command.

Comment: Another variant: `awk '/^UNIX$/ {s=NR;next} s && NR<=s+2'`

Comment: I know that @cuonglm

Comment: @Cold: What is your OS?

Comment: SunOS 5.10 Generic 147440-12

Comment: @Cold: `awk` in SunOS is an old program, you should use `nawk` instead.

Comment: I will try now... wait

Answer (score 15):

A `grep` solution:

```
grep -A2 -P '^UNIX$' file
```

**Explanation:** `-A` means: print the next two lines after the match

Or `awk:`

```
awk '$0=="UNIX"{getline; print; getline; print}' file
```

**Explanation:** Search for UNIX in the line (`$0=="UNIX"`). If found, get the next line into the buffer (`getline`) and print the buffer (`print`). This is done twice.

Or use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^UNIX$/{n;p;n;p}' file
```

**Explanation:** Search for UNIX (`/^UNIX$/`). If found, execute the part in the `{...}`. `n` means next, `p` means print. This is done twice as well.

Comment: Thanks @chaos, i will trys the last 2 option that you give. PLease append some explanation of each option, i wonna compreend and do.

Comment: If the number of lines changes, how many changes i will make on last two options? Thanks

Comment: @Cold see my edit. To change the number if lines repeat the `getline; print;` part in the `awk` statement or the `n;p;` part in the `sed` statement.

Comment: Thanks @chaos, but the higher the number of lines is increased expression and the change is not feasible in my opinion. Do not you think? If 100 lines?

Comment: @Cold Then I would use the grep solution with `grep -A100 -P '^UNIX$' file | tail -n +2`. The tail part is to remove the first lien. In the others (sed, awk) you would have to write loops, what makes it less simple.

Comment: @Cold: You can use the `awk` solution from @cuonglm.

Comment: Why are you using `-P`? There's nothing in your regex that requires PCRE.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson True, but I always use the -P flag, I accustomed that to myself. From the different implementations of `grep` the -P flag should always be the same.

Comment: Note that the first (`grep`) solution prints "UNIX" and then the two following line. The OP asked to just print the two following lines. The last two solutions perform the requested task. The `grep` solution could be `grep -A2 '^UNIX$' test | grep -v UNIX`.

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -A 2 UNIX file.txt
```

The manpage of grep describes the option thus:

```
  -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
      Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
      Places  a  line  containing  --  between  contiguous  groups  of
      matches.
```

Comment: Hi @Twinkles, good answer, but my grep has only this options "hblcnsviw". But the logics is good. thanks

Comment: This will print `UNIX` in output, too.

Comment: To omit the `UNIX`, pipe it to `tail`:  `[...] | tail -n +1`, or to `sed`: `[...] | sed '1d'`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: your `tail` and `sed '1d'` suggestions work correctly only if `UNIX` appears only once in the input text. All the other answers allow for multiple occurrences. It might be better to suggest `... | grep -v UNIX`. Admittedly, this gets messy if `UNIX` appears on lines 15 and 17.

Comment: Good points.  I'm pretty sure it could just be done in `sed` with some form of `sed '/UNIX/d;n;n;p/' /path/to/file`, which I just sussed out and submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick nicely:

```
sed -n '/UNIX/{n;p;n;p}' /path/to/file
```

Proof of concept:

```
$ for i in {1..9}; do echo $i; done | sed -n '/4/{n;p;n;p}'
5
6
```

Comment: The subshell around your `for` loop isn't necessary.

Comment: Indeed it is not; it was a remnant of some other faffery I was in the midst of on that shell earlier in the day.  Parens removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ex`:

```
ex -s +'1,/UNIX/d|%p|q!' file_or_/dev/stdin
```

where:

- `1,/UNIX/d` - [removes text after match](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4273/467)
- `%p` - prints buffer
- `q!` - quit without saving changes to file (use `wq` to edit in-place)